# Regex for sed/awk command

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I would like to change the file content which i specified like below.I want to comment out all the lines which contains ".class" except the class name i provide.

```
@MyClass1.MyClass2(value = {
    Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
    Class3.class,
    Class4.class
})
public class Foo {}
```

For example if i provide Class2 as parameter to

```
sed -i -E 's/some_regex/Class2/g'
```

command,the result should be like this,

```
@MyClass1.MyClass2(value = {
    //Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
    //Class3.class,
    //Class4.class
})
public class Foo {}
```

What regex should i use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file like this:

```
$ cat file1
@MyClass1.MyClass2(value = {
    Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
    Class3.class,
    Class4.class
})
public class Foo {}
@MyClass11.MyClass2(value = {
    Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
    Class3.class,
    Class4.class
})
public class Foo2 {}
```

You can have this result:

```
$ sed '/@MyClass1.MyClass2(*/,/})/{s|\sClass.*|//&|g; /Class2/{s|//||}}' file1
@MyClass1.MyClass2(value = {
   // Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
   // Class3.class,
   // Class4.class
})
public class Foo {}
@MyClass11.MyClass2(value = {
    Class1.class,
    Class2.class,
    Class3.class,
    Class4.class
})
public class Foo2 {}
```

Explanation:

`'/@MyClass1.MyClass2(*/,/})/ {....}` --> range to operate in form `/from/,/to/{actions}`

`{s|\sClass.*|//&|g;`  --> apply `//` in all lines starting with whitespace `\s` and then `Class`

`/Class2/{s|//||}`    --> remove `//` for `Class2`

Tip: In sed we can use any char as a separator for `s/replacethis/withthat/` synthax.
I choose `|` to avoid escaping `//`

Comment: I like how you removed the comment from `Class2`.

Comment: Great answer,but i am just wondering, what if i want to apply // in all lines ending with .class? What regex should i use instead of {s|\sClass.*|//&|g; ?

Comment: @aekber Maybe something like `s|\.class$|//&|g`. The use of `$` is a regex anchor that means "end of line".

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\.class/ && !/Class2/ {print "//", $0}
     !(/\.class/ && !/Class2/) {print $0}' filename
```

Comment: I only want to be changed the lines between this annotation @MyClass1.MyClass2(value = {})